# Jquery get all input values and create an array (with names)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, forms

Hay guys, I'm doing some work where i have a large collection of forms. Seems these aren't 'posted' the traditional way (i.e using a submit button). I need a way to collect all the names and values of all form data when clicking a link (document.location is then used for redirects).

I want names to stay intact so that i can used a simple PHP script to work with the data.

any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Might I suggest [Serialize Form to JSON](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/serialize-form-to-json/):

> ```
> $.fn.serializeObject = function()
> {
>    var o = {};
>    var a = this.serializeArray();
>    $.each(a, function() {
>        if (o[this.name]) {
>            if (!o[this.name].push) {
>                o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
>            }
>            o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
>        } else {
>            o[this.name] = this.value || '';
>        }
>    });
>    return o;
> };
> ```

and then you can do:

```
var formArray = $("#myform").serializeObject();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$.fn.valuesArr = function()
{
    var a = [];
    jQuery.each(this, function(i, field){
        a.push($.trim(field.value));
    });
    return a;
}
```

USE:

```
var myArr = $('input', $parentJQelem).valuesArr();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like my submit helper as a base

```
function submit(form) {
  var form = $(form);
  $.ajax(
    { data: $.param( form.serializeArray()),
      dataType:'script',
      type:'post',
      url: form.attr("action")});
}
```

instead of a 'serializeArray()' i would use 'serialize()' and instead of posting it using ajax you could do whatever you want.

Sorry, dont have more time right now, but hopefully this snippet helps you.

Comment: I think the combination of $.param and form.serializeArray() is the key. not seralize :). but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

[cletus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789901/jquery-get-all-input-values-and-create-an-array-with-names/1789929#1789929)'s answer is the best one in terms of efficency.

This is however another working solution that does not rely on JSON:

```
//this is my object I will fill my array with
function myObject(name, value)
{
    this.name = name;
    this.value = value;
}

var arr = $.map(
    $('span'), function (item) {
       var $item = $(item); //no need to $(item) 2 times
       return new 
         myObject(
           $item.attr("name"),     //name field
           $item.text()            //value field
         );
    }
);
```

`arr` will be an array of `myObject`, each of them containing a `name` property and a `value` property.

Use your selector instead of `$('span')`.

Answer (score 0):

but all this functions dont work witch array names in inputs.

example -

this is correct for submit post form but when serialize i get

form[type[]]:2

this is not correct - i need - form[type][]:2